# Trying to convert data long format to wide format

Tags: r

My data frame currently looks like

```
country_txt  Year nkill_yr Countrycode Population deathsPer100k
        <chr> <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>         <dbl>
1 Afghanistan  1973        0           4      12028  0.000000e+00
2 Afghanistan  1979       53           4      13307  3.982866e-05
3 Afghanistan  1987        0           4      11503  0.000000e+00
4 Afghanistan  1988      128           4      11541  1.109089e-04
5 Afghanistan  1989       10           4      11778  8.490406e-06
6 Afghanistan  1990       12           4      12249  9.796718e-06
```

It contains a list of al countries, and the terrorist Deaths per 100,000 population.

Ideally I would Like a data frame in wide format that has the structure of:

```
country_txt 1970 1971 1972  1973 1974 1975
Afghanistan 3.98 1.1  0     4.3  0.8  0.09
Albania     0    0.4  0.5   0    0    0
Algeria     0    0    0     0.1  0.2  0
Angola      0    0.3  0     0    0    0
```

Except my function currently repeats like this:

```
YearCountryRatio<- spread(data = YearCountryRatio, Year, deathsPer100k )

country_txt 1970 1971 1972 1973
Afghanistan 3.98 NA   NA   NA
Afghanistan NA   1.1  NA   NA
Afghanistan NA   NA   0    NA
Afghanistan NA   NA   NA   4.3
```

And similarly for other countries,

Is there any way to either:

1. Collapse all of the NA values to show only one country or
2. Put it directly into wide format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've assumed you want each `country_txt` value reduced to a single row and are happy to drop the unused variables. (Note: I added a dummy `country_txt` value of `"XYZ"` to the sample data to show how multiple countries spread)

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- read.table(text = "country_txt  Year nkill_yr Countrycode Population deathsPer100k
1 Afghanistan  1973        0           4      12028  0.000000e+00
2 Afghanistan  1979       53           4      13307  3.982866e-05
3 Afghanistan  1987        0           4      11503  0.000000e+00
4 XYZ          1988      128           4      11541  1.109089e-04
5 XYZ          1989       10           4      11778  8.490406e-06
6 XYZ          1990       12           4      12249  9.796718e-06", header = TRUE)

df <- mutate(df, deathsPer100k = round(deathsPer100k*100000, 2))
select(df, country_txt, Year, deathsPer100k) %>% spread(Year, deathsPer100k, fill = 0)
#>   country_txt 1973 1979 1987  1988 1989 1990
#> 1 Afghanistan    0 3.98    0  0.00 0.00 0.00
#> 2         XYZ    0 0.00    0 11.09 0.85 0.98
```